# How to have two bindings simultaneously to the same widget in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to to perform a fuction when a certain entry ***gets focus AND a key is pressed*** (not just focus alone, nor just key is pressed alone)

I mean something like

```
entry.bind('<FocusIn>', '<Key>', myFunction)
```

I kow that I can check for focus first then apply the function when the key is pressed, but I was wondering if I can just make it like above in some way.

Answer (score 0):

No there actually isn't a way to do this. I wasn't sure myself so i tried something like:

```
root.bind('<FocusIn-Key>',callback) #callback=print
```

and:

```
root.bind('<Key-FocusIn>',callback) #callback=print
```

but nothing worked. So I would say binding `'<Key>'`-sequence and checking for focus will be the best solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible to combine to bindings somehow using some tomfoolery, however, a combination of getting focus and a keyboard event is simply impossible because the widget only begins to look for keyboard events **after** it is in focus. If this was not the case, what you are asking for would be possible, but it would also mean that if you had multiple widgets bound to keyboard events, they would all activate when you type characters. 
Like I said in the beginning, there might be ways to work it so that if you press two keys simultaneously you can run you desired function. But a mouse click and a keyboard event would only be possible after an initial mouse click (which is a little bit redundant).